# How to read Date from an Excel using Selenium WebDriver and return it?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read date from Excel file but its giving the following Exception:

```
Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell.
```

And I want to return `cellData` whatever it may be(string, int, date).

Here's my code:

```
public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum, String SheetName ) throws Exception{
                try{
                    ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
                    Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);                      
                    String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();                        
                    return CellData;
                 }catch (Exception e){
                     Log.error("Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception desc : "+e.getMessage());
                     DriverScript.bResult = false;
                     return"";
                     }
                 }
```

Comment: copy your error message here also so other can understand the issue better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apeksha Pawar please do one thing in your excel sheet where you are keeping date please change the format of that cell to string one of the way to do that is :

```
suppose your date is 04/01/2016  then add a Single "'" (comma) in front of the date value it will change its format to string and after that your above code will work.
```

there are multiple ways to do the same please follow your excel guidelines

Comment: Awsome! Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Try to use String Split while taking date and time as by default it takes both.

Comment: can you share code which shows the usage of "string split" for the question asked